# Cannot assign value of type '()' to type 'String!'

Tags: swift, printing, uitextfield

I would like to print my result into show (UITextField), but I failed.
What's wrong with the code?

Getting error message:

Cannot assign value of type '()' to type 'String!'

Code snippet:

```
@IBOutlet weak var x1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var x2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var y1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var y2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var z: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var show: UITextView!

@IBAction func result(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let X1 = Int(x1.text!)!
    let X2 = Int(x2.text!)!
    let Y1 = Int(y1.text!)!
    let Y2 = Int(y2.text!)!
    let Z = Int(z.text!)!

    if X1...X2 ~= Z || Y1...Y2 ~= Z {
        for X in stride(from: X1, to: Z, by: 1) {
            for Y in stride(from: Y1, to: Z, by: 1) {
                print("   \(X) × \(Y) = \(X * Y) ,", terminator:"")
            }}
        for X in stride(from: Z+1, through: X2, by: 1) {
            for Y in stride(from: Z+1, through: Y2, by: 1) {
                print("   \(X) × \(Y) = \(X * Y) ,", terminator:"")
            }}
    }else{
        for X in stride(from: X1, through: X2, by: 1) {
            for Y in stride(from: Y1, through: Y2, by: 1) {
               print("   \(X) × \(Y) = \(X * Y) ,", terminator:"")
                }}
        }
    show.text = print("")
```

Comment: You have tagged the question `Objective-C` but your code is `Swift`

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more about your code.?